# Localhost can't get bundle file

Tags: javascript, get

I am getting an error when trying to `get` a page: http://localhost:3000/homepage.bundle.js

app.js:

```
app.get('/logged_in', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/logged_in.html');
});
```

webpack.prod.config.js

```
"build": "NODE_ENV=production ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config ./webpack.prod.config.js --progress --colors",
```

I know this isn't much code, I can post more but can't work out why it won't `get` this.

Comment: did you run the command npm run build before running server. and also what is you webpack.config output file name

Comment: yes i did run that command

Comment: Just one more question have you configured node to serve static files